# Update and select id for multiple (3) querys

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

Setup: mysql, php

Table looke like:

```
usermissionid  |  userid  |  missionid  | value
```

Rows look like:

```
h5s6l4  |  h5s6l  |  4  |  0
h5s6l2  |  h5s6l  |  2  |  0
h5s6l6  |  h5s6l  |  6  |  0
```

I create for each user 3 rows (3 missions) and need to update them on a daily basis once with 3 random missionids. After update i need to obtain the updated missionids.
**What would be the best way for best performance / least overheat ?**  
I have prepared some examples:

1. **Update 3 rows** according user id, generate mission ids with mysql, and **select 3 rows** after. 
   Disadventage: missionids have to be unique for each user, i have to catch an error and rerun the query or find a way to avoid rand() throw same values

   ```
    UPDATE 
    missions
    SET
    value = 0, missionid = CEIL((RAND() + 0.001) * (25) -0.025), usermissionid = CONCAT(userid, missionid)
    WHERE 
    userid = 'h5s6l'    

   SELECT 
    missionid
   FROM 
    missions
   WHERE
    userid = 'h5s6l'
   ```
2. Create missionids with php, **4 *separate* update querys** (store old missions, select query is done anyway) inside a for loop

   ```
    usermissionids[0] = h5s6l4; ...
    for(i=0; i < 3, i++){
    NEWmusermissionids[0] = h5s6l7
        NEWmissionids[0] = 7  // random()
    ...
        UPDATE 
        missions
        SET
        value = 0, missionid = '7', usermissionid = 'h5s6l7'
            WHERE 
        userid = 'h5s6l'
    ...     
    }UPDATE 
            user
            SET
            oldmissionids = '2|6|7'
                WHERE 
            userid = 'h5s6l'
   ```
3. **Delete all rows**, create missionids with php, **insert 3 *separate*  querys**.

   ```
   DELETE  
   FROM
       quests
   WHERE
       userid = h5s6l

   for(i=0; i < 3, i++){
   NEWmusermissionids[0] = h5s6l7
       NEWmissionids[0] = 7  // random()
   ...
   INSERT INTO
       quests (usermissionid, userid, missionid, value)
   VALUES
       (h5s6l7, h5s6l, 7, 0)
   ...
   }
   ```
4. EDIT I got a new idea by using a set number, each set number contains 3 fixed missionids. For this one i need to update all missions daylie once and reset value to 0:
   disadventage: currently there are 16 missions (can grow at ~ 30) -> 16 permanent rows (take space, **16 update querys**,  many rows performance on select ?). I need to find a way to insert the query in case update wasnt successful ('replace' or 'update on duplicate')

```
    UPDATE 
        missions
    SET
        value = 0
    WHERE 
        userid = 'h5s6l'
```

5. EDIT I could try to use php and improve 4. As result i have to send **3 *separate* update querys** :
   usermissionids would be fixed values and look like: h5s6l1, h5s6l2, h5s6l3

   ```
    $curset[] = 1,4,6
    for(i=0; i < 3, i++){
    ...
        UPDATE 
        missions
        SET
        value = 0, missionid = $curset[i]
            WHERE 
        userid = 'h5s6l'
    ...     
    }
   ```
6. Do you have a better idea ? Might there be a better way of organizing the table ?

Comment: What queries will be done on the Table?  I need to know to see whether it makes sense to store the missions in a single column, a la `"4,2,6"`

Comment: @RickJames      On this table i do the following queries. 
1. update and select all once (values are stored and updated in a session until logout), 
2. update - sync the progress (value). For the progress there are 16 different missions. For each mission you have to complete different tasks. For example if you have to collect 10 things for task 4 i probably will add 10 for each collect. If he reaches 100 he gets rewarded. 

The table wich would store "4,2,6" is selected anyway because each call requires to fetch the user for authentification.

->

Comment: It just could get messy to update the progress, but i can store the progress on the same table like "0,0,0" so i dont have to do another select. Only 1 update with this methode. The only thing i fear it is not future friendly. But for the moment it sound pretty good as there wont be more then 3 quests daylie for a while probably.